# Is it possible (how) to add a spot color to pdf from matplotlib?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, colors

I am creating a chart which has to use (multiple) spot colors. This color could be one that is neither accessible from RGB nor CMYK. Is there a possibility to specify a spot color for a line in matplotlib and export this to pdf? Direct export is preferred but not necessary.

**Note:** A [spot color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_color) is a color that is not necessarily set before printing and has just a representation color until then. In the pdf it is represented as an separate color channel.[image: How to spot a spot color in Adoce Acrobat Pro]

Comment: I don't believe that matplotlib supports this; there's no mention of an implementation of this in the documentation.

Comment: 99% sure mpl does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this recently, I don't know if you managed to find it, but ReportLab has a method that is PCMYKColorSep.

So you could integrate the graph from matplotlib within a reportlab canvas, and add as many color separations as you see fitting.

The example above doesn't actually integrate with matplotlib, but it does add the spot

```
c = Canvas('test.pdf', (420, 200))
language_spot = PCMYKColorSep(0.0, 100.0, 91.0, 0.0, spotName='LanguageSpot', density=100)
c.setFillColor(language_spot)
c.rect(300, 75, 100, 100, fill=True, stroke=False)
c.save()
```