# Extract path or position information about all objects in a matplotlibfigure

Tags: python, serialization, matplotlib

I want to export information about all visible objects in a matplotlib figure, however I can not find the arguments that give me the position. Basically I am trying to serialize it. I already read [matplotlib figure serialization](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/matplotlib-figure-serialization-td18587.html) and I agree it is better to serialize code rather than the information, but matplotlib can not fully satisfy my needs ([Spot Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523328/is-it-possible-how-to-add-a-spot-color-to-pdf-from-matplotlib)), so I want to send all information to pdflib, which is able to do that.

I am as far as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(10)
y = [c**2 for c in x]

fig, sp = plt.subplots(1,1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()

path = sp.get_children()[0].get_path()
for vertex in path.iter_segments():
    print(vertex)
```

to export the path of my dataline, which works fine. But I cannot get my hands on the paths/lines of the <s>axis</s>, ticks or <s>gridlines</s>. The positions are a start, but I need the endpoints, too.

It would be most helpful, if you supply the coordinate system they are in, too, so I can apply the correct tranformation.

**EDIT:**

Found the axis to be the spines in data coordinates.
Found the gridlines as part of the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `get_children` you get only children objects, but these objects may have own children. However not all objects have `get_path` method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_info(obj):
    if 'get_children' in dir(obj):
        for o in obj.get_children():
            print o
            if('get_path' in dir(o)): print o.get_path()
            get_info(o)

x = range(10)
y = [c**2 for c in x]
fig,sp = plt.subplots(1,1)
plt.plot(x,y)

get_info(fig)
```

Output:

```
Rectangle(0,0;1x1)
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.]]), array([ 1,  2,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8))
Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
Line2D(_line0)
Path(array([[  0.,   0.],
       [  1.,   1.],
       [  2.,   4.],
       [  3.,   9.],
       [  4.,  16.],
       [  5.,  25.],
       [  6.,  36.],
       [  7.,  49.],
       [  8.,  64.],
       [  9.,  81.]]), None)
Spine
Path(array([[ 13.,   1.],
       [ 13.,   1.]]), None)
Spine
Path(array([[  1.,  13.],
       [  1.,  13.]]), None)
Spine
Path(array([[ 13.,   0.],
       [ 13.,   0.]]), None)
Spine
Path(array([[  0.,  13.],
       [  0.,  13.]]), None)
XAxis(80.000000,48.000000)
Text(0.5,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x104447f90>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x1045e6050>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x10720ac50>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x1072230d0>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x107223810>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x107223f50>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x10722c6d0>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x10722ce10>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x107237590>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.XTick object at 0x107237cd0>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(0,1))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
YAxis(80.000000,48.000000)
Text(0,0.5,u'')
Text(0,0.5,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x1045c29d0>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x104447f10>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x107241990>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x107246410>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x107246910>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x107251090>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x1072517d0>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x107237f50>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x10725c310>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
<matplotlib.axis.YTick object at 0x10725ca50>
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D()
Path(array([[ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Line2D((0,0),(1,0))
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.]]), None)
Text(0,0,u'')
Text(1,0,u'')
Text(0.5,1,u'')
Text(0,1,u'')
Text(1,1,u'')
Rectangle(0,0;1x1)
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.]]), array([ 1,  2,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8))
```